# Ajax_view data in not rendering to views

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-templates, django-views

[image]

I have a question about views and ajax-view communication through urls.py files.

I am implementing pagination using ajax_views.

For that purpose, I have written function definition in ajax_views.py and from function sending response as 'HttpResponse' from that function.
And in the views.py I am sending NULL request because I want to render the data from ajax_views.
In the urls.py, I have mapped the URL maps to forward the supported URLs.

Ajax_views is working fine and is able to see data on ajax_views, but the issue is in views, I am not getting the data from ajax_views. View is showing empty page.

See the image above.

What exactly is missing?

Comment: Your code is missing from the question.

Comment: pseudo code updated @ https://pastebin.com/6Ez3pEEP